# Cannot set the Datasetname in a hdf5 file by slicing

Tags: hdf5, python-3.7, h5py

I'm trying to store 3 datasets in a hdf5 file by unsing h5py. The name of each dataset is extraced by a slicing but that doesn't work.

```py
# First I open a .png image file and convert this image to an numpy array
# called "raster":
.
.
.
# The second step is, that i'm trying to extract the datasetname by a slicing
# on the filename to give the dataset a name:

filename = imagefile1.png

dsetName = filename[:-4]

# Then i open a hdf5 file by:

file = h5py.File('hdf5_file.5h', 'a')

# and write the dataset into that file:

file.create_dataset(dsetName, data=raster)
```

But at this point i always run into the same issue:

AttributeError: 'slice' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Shouldn't there be quotes around `imagefile1.png` in the first line (`filename = imagefile1.png`)? I don't see how this example would get beyond that line otherwise.

Comment: I added quotes myself and your example created a valid HDF5 file (after I added some imports and defined a fake raster array myself, please add those yourself next time). I would print the contents of filename before and after you make the slice, to see what's happening there.